# I2C LCD with LCM1602 module

Tags: i2c, java

I bought this LCD:  https://www.sunfounder.com/i2clcd.html

And I want to use it under Java program, for example with pi4j framework.
Being I2C restricts a lot the examples I found and in that world, people usually speak about I2C with module MCP23017, MCP23008... or similar.

Isn't it possible to use my module in Java? Any easy example?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking/asking at http://pi4j.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through this [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=947711#p947711) post which seems to offer a working solution or at least a start point.

If you can program there are many Python examples which should be easily portable to Java, e.g. my http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_i2c_lcd_py

Comment: I'm trying to make it work with diozero labrary but still not

Comment: Which backend are you using?  I thought it worked if the pigpio backend was used (disclaimer, I wrote pigpio but have nothing to do with Java or the diozero backend).

Comment: Do you mean provider? I was using Pi4J.

Comment: @carduque Possibly, it sounds like what I would call a backend.